# How to print online friends name in FB using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I wrote the below code to check if it is storing the list from chatbox.PlzAdd necessary code to it to do the same. Thnx in advance.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.fb.com");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'email']")).sendKeys("******");


driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id = 'pass']")).sendKeys("*******");

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='submit']")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Profile']")));

Thread.sleep(10000);

//This is path for the friends in the chat box, but its saying not able to find element
List<WebElement> friendsOnChatBox = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class = '_42fz']"));

System.out.println("The No Of Friends in chatbox is: "+ friendsOnChatBox.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in your code Idk how you have executed it.There will be a `ClassCastException` thrown at runtime for the following as you are casting `WebElement` to `List<WebElement>`.It should be `findElements` not `findElement`

```
 //This is path for the friends in the chat box, but its saying not able to find element
List<WebElement> friendsOnChatBox = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class = '_42fz']"));
```

Any how I've altered the xpath to be more specific and this will do the job neatly

```
   List<WebElement> friendsOnChatBox =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class = '_42fz']//div[@class = '_55lr']"));

    System.out.println("The No Of Friends in chatbox is: " + friendsOnChatBox.size());

    for (WebElement friends : friendsOnChatBox) {
        System.out.println(friends.getText());
    }
```

Comment: You can accept that as answer if it solved your problem(I hope it will)

Comment: It is printing null. Can you please give me the code for printing the above mentioned question. Thanx in advance.

Comment: is it printing only null values?whats the list size?